# Procedure com parâmetro out (SYSREFCURSOR) com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle, iis, stored-procedures

estou com um problema que está me tirando o sono. Estou realizando uma migração de banco de dados, de SQL Server para Oracle, em uma aplicação C#. A aplicação mencionada, está usando Entity Framework para realizar o acesso ao banco.

Consegui migrar a base e o acesso ao banco com tranquilidade, porém, existe uma procedure que retorna um *"ComplexType"*, dei uma pesquisada e descobri que o Oracle não entende o *ComplexType* e que preciso realizar o mapeamento do parâmetro *output* no *web.config*, logo:

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <implicitRefCursor>
        <storedProcedure schema="ALERTA_MPLUS" name="PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO">
          <refCursor name="CV_1">
            <bindInfo mode="Output" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="0" columnName="Broker" baseColumnName="Broker" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="Varchar2" providerType="Varchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="1" columnName="Companhia" baseColumnName="Companhia" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="Varchar2" providerType="Varchar2" columnSize="100" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="2" columnName="Metrica" baseColumnName="Metrica" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="Varchar2" providerType="Varchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="3" columnName="Q1" baseColumnName="Q1" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="NVarchar2" providerType="NVarchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="4" columnName="Q2" baseColumnName="Q2" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="NVarchar2" providerType="NVarchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="5" columnName="Q3" baseColumnName="Q3" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="NVarchar2" providerType="NVarchar2" columnSize="50" />
            <metadata columnOrdinal="6" columnName="Q4" baseColumnName="Q4" baseSchemaName="ALERTA_MPLUS" baseTableName="tt_Resultado_Final" nativeDataType="NVarchar2" providerType="NVarchar2" columnSize="50" />
          </refCursor>
        </storedProcedure>
      </implicitRefCursor>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

Este mapeamento funcionou perfeitamente no ambiente de desenvolvimento, porém quando passei a aplicação para homologação deu o seguinte erro:
[image: Erro no servidor de homologação]
Já tentei algumas soluções mas nenhuma teve sucesso:

- Instalei o ODAC no servidor de homologação;
- Procurando, encontrei uma documentação do Oracle que indica o mapeamento dessa forma:

  ```
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursor.CV_1" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.0" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Broker;BaseColumnName=Broker;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.1" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Companhia;BaseColumnName=Companhia;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.2" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Metrica;BaseColumnName=Metrica;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.3" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Q1;BaseColumnName=Q1;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=NVarchar2;ProviderType=NVarchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.4" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Q2;BaseColumnName=Q2;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=NVarchar2;ProviderType=NVarchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.5" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Q3;BaseColumnName=Q3;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=NVarchar2;ProviderType=NVarchar2'" />
      <add name="ALERTA_MPLUS.PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO.RefCursorMetaData.CV_1.Column.6" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=Q4;BaseColumnName=Q4;BaseSchemaName=ALERTA_MPLUS;BaseTableName=tt_Resultado_Final;NATIVEDATATYPE=NVarchar2;ProviderType=NVarchar2'" />
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
  ```

Esse código retorna o seguinte erro (em **todos** os ambientes):

```
     ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 8: PLS-00306:
     wrong number or types of arguments in call to
     'PR_CONSULTA_DADOS_ROBO' ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 8: PL/SQL:
     Statement ignored;
```

- Publiquei a aplicação em outra máquina (de outro desenvolvedor) e também funcionou;

Algumas informações que acho que são necessárias:

- Visual Studio 2013;
- Oracle.DataAcess.dll versão 4.121.1.0;
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll versão 4.121.1.0;
- ISS 7.0;

**Atualização 11/11/14**

Se eu coloco o código do `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` no `machine.config` funciona. Quando eu recorto do `machine.config` e coloco no `web.config` para de funcionar e retorna o mesmo erro.

Existe algum outro arquivo de configuração? Além do `machine.config` e do `web.config`?
Acho estranho funcionar em um e no outro não.

Se puderem me ajudar...

Desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: O Application Pool da sua aplicação está 32 ou 64 bits?

Comment: 32 bits. Em todos os ambientes.

Comment: O arquivo `machine.config` tem alguma configuração desse tipo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez sim. Possui a configuração do ManagedDataAccess.<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="4.121.1.0">
      <settings>
        <setting name="tns_admin" value="c:\app\mjv\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>

Comment: Você não deve definir assim. Ou as configurações ficam no `Web.config` ou ficam no `machine.config`, mesmo que configurando coisas diferentes. Deve ser essa a causa do seu problema.

Comment: Já retirei essas informações do machine.config e, além de continuar com o erro citado, quando testei as outras funcionalidades deram erro na dll do Oracle.

Comment: O erro acontece ao juntar as configurações do `machine.config` e `Web.config`? Ou você simplesmente apagou a declaração no `machine.config`? Quais são os novos erros?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez estou em casa agora e não consigo ver mas, uma coisa eu te garanto, na minha máquina o machine.config também tem essa configuração do ManagedDataAccess e funciona normalmente.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez fiz o teste tirando do machine.config e adicionando a informação no web.config. O erro foi exatamente igual ao print acima. Mas obrigado pela sugestão. Tem mais alguma? rs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muitos testes e erros consegui resolver. Não sei se é a melhor solução mas resolvi.

No `machine.config` existe uma definição do `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>`:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</configSections>
```

Então adicionei essa declaração no `web.config` e funcionou perfeitamente. Creio que o `web.config` não esteja juntando as configurações do `machine.config`.

Caso tenham problemas parecidos tentem isso que pode funcionar.

Comment: Era só isso? Puxa vida. +1.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez É... Achei estranho não dar conflito com o `machine.config`, quando colei a mesma tag no `web.config` mas funcionou perfeitamente e não prejudicou nenhuma das outras aplicações.